# JS global variable is reading undefined

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I globally defined variable Product ID as such

```
      var ProductID = {};
```

then I assign the click Id of an element to the global variable as such

```
       (function($){
                    $(document).on('click', '.text-left', (function(){

                      ClickedProductId = $(this).closest("td").prop('id');
                   ProductID.value = ClickedProductId;
                        console.log(ClickedProductId);
                        console.log(ProductID.value);

                   }));

                })(jQuery);
```

I was able to verify the clickedID has been added to ProductID in the console from the above log.

now I want to use the same ProductID.value in a new function as such but the ProductID.value becomes undefined.

```
  function OPENITEMDETAIL(){
                        console.log(ProductID.value);

                  $('.ProductDetail').addClass('is-visible');
                 }
```

I need to use the ProductID.value in other functions. what am I doing wrong? how can I fix it?
This is the complete code

html

```
                           <td class="text-left" id="${key}" onclick="OPENITEMDETAIL();"><a href>${key}</a href></td>
```

Javascript

```
        (function($){
                    $(document).on('click', '.text-left', (function(){

                      ClickedProductId = $(this).closest("td").prop('id');
                   ProductID.value = ClickedProductId;
                        console.log(ClickedProductId);

                   }));

                })(jQuery);


  // VIEW ITEM DETAIL 


  function OPENITEMDETAIL(){
              console.log("ITEm DETAIL VIEW opened and activated");
                        console.log(ProductID.value);
              event.preventDefault();


                  $('.ProductDetail').addClass('is-visible');

                var productcontainer = document.getElementById('ProductDetailPage'); 
                   productcontainer.innerHTML = '';


                firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    database = firebase.database();

                    var BusinessesId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

                    return database.ref('/Businesses/' + BusinessesId + '/Inventory/' + ItemID.value ).once('value').then(function(snapshot) { 


                                       var ProductResults = snapshot.val();
                                        var ResultCard = `
                                             ......


                                            `
                                            productcontainer.innerHTML += ResultCard;

                    })

              }
              })
            }
```

Comment: When are you calling OPENITEMDETAIL? If you are calling it before you click on the .text-left element, then it isnt going to be defined yet

Comment: just right below  the function that generate the clickedID

Comment: it will be easy find the issue if you give some fiddle example or complete js code

Comment: This is a good example of why global variables are a bad practice and a terrible waste of time to troubleshoot...

Comment: If you mean `(function($){...})(jQuery); OPEITEMDETAIL()` that isn't going to work like you think it is. Your code isn't going to wait for a click event and then run the rest of the code

Comment: @Christopher any recommendation for alternatives

Comment: @e.iluf pass your variable around as a parameter. Your onclick handler can call your second function directly with the desired value for example. Other advanced options include things like observables and flux stores to control the flow of data. If you provide a more complete code sample we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @PatrickEvans so what should I do to able to access the clicked Id somewhere else in my code?

Comment: If you call the function before the user clicks.... it does not magically rerun the code in the function when the user clicks. You would need to call it..

Comment: @Christopher I have updated it with a more complete code

Answer (score -2):

As ProductID is a variable, assign a value to it directly with '=' sign.
  e.g., if you want it to be an array, ProductID = [ClickedProductId]

e.g., just a primitive value then ProductID  = ClickedProductId